# Unit Test RichSinkFunction in Flink

Tags: mocking, mockito, apache-flink

I have RichSinkFunction with custom metrics that increments every data enters at invoke().
The problem is I cannot mock the Counter.customMetric as they are being initialized at open().

How can I unit test this Counter?

```
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception { 
  
  this.customMetric = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup().counter("myCounter");

}

public invoke(MyData myData, Context context) throws Exception {

    this.customMetric().inc();
    LOG.info(this.customMetric().getCount());
}
```

I am using Junit5 and Mockito. Mocking it still null, I can only mock objects when passed to constructor of my CustomRichSinkFunction class.

Comment: This feels like a Mockito question, but...can't you mock the `getRuntimeContext()` call, so that it returns a mock object which will return a mocked counter when `counter()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked through the following several approaches to testing metrics:

#### 1. Flink MiniCluster with custom MetricReporterFactory (the most difficult but correct in terms of approach)

For tests you will need a custom implementation of `org.apache.flink.metrics.reporter.MetricReporterFactory`:

```java
public class MemorizingTestMetricReporterFactory implements MetricReporterFactory {

    @Override
    public MetricReporter createMetricReporter(Properties properties) {
        return new MemorizingTestMetricReporter();
    }
}
```

This factory returns your new test class that implements `org.apache.flink.metrics.reporter.MetricReporter`:

```java
public class MemorizingTestMetricReporter implements MetricReporter {
    private static final Map<String, Metric> metricsByName = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static Map<String, Metric> getRegisteredMetrics() {
        return new HashMap<>(metricsByName);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(MetricConfig config) {
        // no op
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        metricsByName.clear()
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyOfAddedMetric(Metric metric, String metricName, MetricGroup group) {
        metricsByName.put(metricName, metric);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyOfRemovedMetric(Metric metric, String metricName, MetricGroup group) {
        metricsByName.remove(metricName);
    }
}
```

In this class we store all the metrics that will be recorded in the static collection.

In order for this factory to be visible in tests, you need to add a file to the path `test/resources/META-INF/services/` with the name `org.apache.flink.metrics.reporter.MetricReporterFactory` and the contents `<your_package>.MemorizingTestMetricReporterFactory`

The next step is the test itself with raising and setting up a [minicluster](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#testing-flink-jobs):

```java
@Test
@SneakyThrows
void testByFlinkMiniCluster() {
    // given
    // Todo: Create Flink miniCluster by Junit Extension
    // configure minicluster
    final var miniClusterConfig = new Configuration();
    miniClusterConfig.setString(ConfigConstants.METRICS_REPORTER_PREFIX + "test." + MetricOptions.REPORTER_FACTORY_CLASS.key(), MemorizingTestMetricReporterFactory.class.getName());
    final var miniCluster = new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
            new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                    .setConfiguration(miniClusterConfig)
                    .build());
    // start minicluster
    miniCluster.before();

    // when
    final var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    final var sourceData = List.of(MyData.builder().build());
    // your need some Test Unbounded(!!!) Source
    env.addSource(TestUnboundedSource.fromElements(sourceData))
            .returns(MyData.class)
            .addSink(new MyRichSinkFunction());
    final var jobClient = env.executeAsync();

    // then
    await().atMost(ofSeconds(2))
            .until(() -> {
                // check your counter by static map in MemorizingTestMetricReporter.class
                final var myCounter = MemorizingTestMetricReporter.getRegisteredMetrics().get("myCounter");
                return myCounter != null && ((Counter) myCounter).getCount() == sourceData.size();
            });
    jobClient.cancel().get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    miniCluster.after();
}
```

#### 2. Flink TestHarness (simple but requires the use of Flink test harness abstractions)

TestHarness documentation [reference](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#unit-testing-stateful-or-timely-udfs--custom-operators)

```java
@Test
@SneakyThrows
void testByTestHarness() {
    // given
    // metric group for operators
    final var interceptingOperatorMetricGroup = new InterceptingOperatorMetricGroup();
    // metric group for task
    final var interceptingTaskMetricGroup = new InterceptingTaskMetricGroup() {
        @Override
        public InternalOperatorMetricGroup getOrAddOperator(OperatorID operatorID, String name) {
            return interceptingOperatorMetricGroup;
        }
    };
    final var mockEnvironment = new MockEnvironmentBuilder().setMetricGroup(interceptingTaskMetricGroup).build();
    try (final var testHarness = new OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(new StreamSink<>(new MyRichSinkFunction()), mockEnvironment)) {
        testHarness.setup();
        testHarness.open();

        // when
        final var sourceData = List.of(new StreamRecord<>(MyData.builder().build()));
        testHarness.processElements(sourceData);

        // then
        final var myCounter = interceptingOperatorMetricGroup.get("myCounter");
        assertNotNull(myCounter, "Counter is null");
        assertEquals(1, ((Counter) myCounter).getCount());
    }
}
```

#### 3. Mock (the worst way)

You can use Mockito, but we are forced to mock knowing the internal implementation of the component, which contradicts the essence of the tests

```java
@Test
@SneakyThrows
void testByMock() {
    // given
    final var myRichSinkFunction = new MyRichSinkFunction();
    final var runtimeContext = mock(RuntimeContext.class);
    myRichSinkFunction.setRuntimeContext(runtimeContext);
    final var metricGroup = mock(OperatorMetricGroup.class);
    doReturn(metricGroup).when(runtimeContext).getMetricGroup();
    when(metricGroup.addGroup(any())).thenReturn(metricGroup);
    final var counter = new Counter() {
        private final AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong();
        @Override
        public void inc() {
            count.incrementAndGet();
        }

        @Override
        public void inc(long n) {
            count.addAndGet(n);
        }

        @Override
        public void dec() {
            count.decrementAndGet();
        }

        @Override
        public void dec(long n) {
            count.getAndUpdate(l -> l - n);
        }

        @Override
        public long getCount() {
            return count.get();
        }
    };
    when(metricGroup.counter(any())).thenReturn(counter);

    // when
    myRichSinkFunction.open(mock(Configuration.class));
    myRichSinkFunction.invoke(new MyData(), mock(SinkFunction.Context.class));

    // then
    final var counterCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    verify(metricGroup, times(1)).counter(counterCaptor.capture());
    assertEquals("myCounter", counterCaptor.getValue());

    assertEquals(1, counter.getCount());
}
```